# Wygwam error "Cannot redeclare class Wygwam" error after 2.7.2 upgrade

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, error, upgrade

After upgrading to 2.7.2, I am getting an odd "Cannot redeclare class Wygwam" error in the control panel.

This prevents entries from opening, and also accessing the Fieldtypes list.

Any solution? It's the latest version of Wygwam (3.2.2).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try removing all Wygwam related files in the third_party directory from the server and readding the 3.2.2 files. Maybe there's a wygwam.bk directory or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Anna! That did the trick (although it's not initializing right now - arrgh.)